# Angular 2 multi step animation

Tags: javascript, angular, animation

I am curious as to whether or not it is possible to do multi step animation with angular 2. I have created a basic animation, where my button slides to the right upon clicking it. However I want to know if I am able to make the buttom move right, then down, or however many more movements I please. I have attempted the following with little success...

```
state('active', style({
  backgroundColor:'blue',
  transform: ' translatey(100%) translatex(100%) '
})),
```

This basically makes the box move diagonally, because both translates are triggered at the same time. I want it to translate one step at a time. Any direction or help would be great. Thank you!

**edit**

As requested [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/RSsRXjx4eDoQArXKtnyp?p=preview)

Comment: Would you like to provide a plunker?

Comment: @Kinduser Added :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the plunker with the solution:

https://plnkr.co/edit/ulE79CSzuxE6DgMshT3W?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, however I am attempting to have it all one animation, rather than having to click everytime.

Comment: Ahh, fine. Let me fix it.

Comment: Edited my post, check it out.

Comment: Is it too much to ask to add details of the multi step animation so that others can learn, instead of just a link?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore I can do it, if you want :)

Answer (score 1):

The way to do that in Angular would be using keyframes.

```
export const move = trigger('move' , [
  state('start', style({ transform: 'translate(0px,0px)' })),
  state('end', style({ transform: 'translate(0px,20px)' })),
  transition('start => end', animate('2s ease-in-out', keyframes([
      style({transform: 'translate(0px,0px)', offset: 0 }),
      style({transform: 'translate(0px,20px)', offset: 0.4 }),
      style({transform: 'translate(20px,20px)', offset: 0.8 }),
      style({transform: 'translate(0px,20px)', offset: 1 })
    ])
  )),
  transition('end => start', animate('2s ease-in-out', keyframes([
      style({transform: 'translate(0px,20px)', offset: 0 }),
      style({transform: 'translate(20px,20px)', offset: 0.4 }),
      style({transform: 'translate(0px,20px)', offset: 0.8 }),
      style({transform: 'translate(0px,0px)', offset: 1 })
    ])
  ))
]);
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2ESNUx8wGFE4j3mu0GtX?p=preview)